# Magento 2 .3.3 installation is stuck at 99 percent?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Installation is incomplete error at 99 percent but when i login to admin panel its working fine .what i next to do ?any one kindly state the issue?

Comment: You can try to install via CLI.

Comment: but admin pannel  is woking fine there is no issue

Comment: so why the installation is incomplete

Comment: maybe you can't find the issue, because it is little.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked with url ? - sometimes it showing 99% due to few configuration of server , but magento 2 is already installed.

so check with the url you have setup magento2 , also check admin as well.

if its not works then post the error log here , so its help us to troubleshoot the issue.